# No_proxy setting ignored?

Tags: proxy

I am on an Ubuntu (20.04) running on VirtualBox. As everything is behind a proxy, I configured the proxy settings and managed to access webpages in the internet (using Firefox). Anyway, I fail to access internal webpages. One internal webservice for example gives a proxy message with a DNS-fail. The internal Gitlab only gives a timeout.

Outside the VM everything works well, so it must have something to do with the proxy settings. But I don't know how to troubleshoot.
My environment variables look like this:

```
no_proxy=99.0.0.0/8,*.xxx.domain.de,localhost,127.0.0.0/8
NO_PROXY=99.0.0.0/8,*.xxx.domain.de,localhost,127.0.0.0/8
http_proxy=http://myproxy.domain.de:80/
HTTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.domain.de:80
https_proxy=http://myproxy.domain.de:80/
HTTPS_PROXY=http://myproxy.domain.de:80
ftp_proxy=http://myproxy.domain.de:80/
FTP_PROXY=http://myproxy.domain.de:80/
```

I am pretty new to proxy configurations as well as to Ubuntu. Please ask, if there is information missing. Can anybody help troubleshooting what's going on and why these internal sites are not reachable?

**Additional things tested:**

```
curl --noproxy '*' http://my.internal.webpage
```

works, but

```
curl http://my.internal.webpage
```

gives

```
curl: (3) Failed to convert myproxy.domain.de to ACE; string contains a disallowed character
```

Comment: A proxy message with a *DNS* fail? Do you mean the proxy server itself couldn't be looked up on DNS, or that the internal site couldn't be looked up? Either way I'd first check whether your DNS setting includes your intranet DNS server

Comment: The internal site could not be looked up. How can I check my DNS setting?

Comment: I did check the DNS-IPs under Network Settings. They look fine as far as I can judge.